# External monitor high latency on reverse-prime intel/nvidia

Tags: xorg, thinkpad, external-monitor, nvidia-prime

## Description

My laptop (Thinkpad X1 Extreme gen 3) suffers from high latency on external monitors (running with display port) when using the `on-demand` Nvidia driver option (version 460). Overall it feels like the display is running at the wrong fps, maybe in the 25-30 range. The display shows up in `xrandr` as being 50hz while in reality it's 60. This problem goes away when the primary gpu is set to the Nvidia one. It should be noted that the external display ports are physically routed through the nvidia gpu, so some latency is to be expected when rendering with the intel gpu, but I don't think it would be that bad.

## Hardware and other info

Thinkpad x1 extreme gen 3
Core i9 10885h
32gb 2933mhz single-channel ram
Intel uhd 630/nvidia 1650ti mobile max-q
Ubuntu 21.04, nvidia-proprietary driver 460, vanilla gnome on x11

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by over-agressive power saving on the internal gpu, causing it to drop render the desktops at a reduced framerate. A solution is to select `Maximum Performance` in the Gnome Settings Power menu on Ubuntu 21.04.